# Pokemon Api with rdx query and react: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've been trying for a while to display data from the Pokemon API in my browser, specifically the data for weight, height, name, and sprites.

Unfortunately, I keep getting an error when I try to map over it. Can someone tell me how to achieve this? What am I doing wrong? Can someone show me how to do it?"

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } from "../Api/pokemonApi";

function PokemonCard() {
  const { data, error, isLoading, isError } = useGetPokemonByNameQuery();
  console.log(data)

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {isLoading && '...Loading...'}
        {isError && error.message}
        {data.map((pokemon) => (
          <li key={pokemon.id}>{pokemon.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
  
export default PokemonCard;
```

```js
const pokemonApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "pokemonApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPokemonByName: builder.query({
      query: () => `/pokemon`,
    }),
  }),
});       
  
export const { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } = pokemonApi;
export default pokemonApi;
```

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import pokemonApi from '../Api/pokemonApi';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [pokemonApi.reducerPath]: pokemonApi.reducer
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    return getDefaultMiddleware().concat(pokemonApi.middleware);
  } 
});

setupListeners(store.dispatch);
```

```
import pokemonApi  from './Api/pokemonApi'
import { ApiProvider } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import PokemonCard from './Components/PokemonCard';

function App() {
  return (
    <ApiProvider api={pokemonApi}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Pokemon</h1>
        <PokemonCard /> 
      </div>
    </ApiProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error coming from? Can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: I think this might be related to the map, or I believe I may have set the endpoints incorrectly? Currently, I'm getting this error message.

data.map is not a function
TypeError: data.map is not a function

Comment: In case you just missed it or haven't taken the full [tour] yet (you earn a badge BTW) there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after [someone answers](/help/someone-answers) that helps rate and curate content on the site.

Answer (score 2):

## Issues

- The pokemon endpoint your are using doesn't return an array, it returns an object with a `results` property that is an array.

  ```json
  // 20231009084854
  // https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon

  {
    "count": 1292,
    "next": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=20&limit=20",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
      {
        "name": "bulbasaur",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
      },
      {
        "name": "ivysaur",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"
      },
      ...,
      {
        "name": "raticate",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/20/"
      }
    ]
  }
  ```
- The RTKQ hooks return undefined `data` initially until data has been fetched and cached. The UI should account for this by using null-checks/guard-clauses on any `data` properties or by using the query status flags, e.g. `isSuccess`, `isError`, etc, to know when/if there is data to render.

## Solution

Trivial solution is to use null-checks on the returned `data` property to access into it the `results` array, e.g. `data?.results.map`.

```
function PokemonCard() {
  const { data, error, isLoading, isError } = useGetPokemonByNameQuery();

  return (
    <ul>
      {isLoading && "...Loading..."}
      {isError && error.message}
      {data?.results.map((pokemon) => (
        <li key={pokemon.name}>{pokemon.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Another trivial solution would be to [transform the response](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#transformresponse). You will still have the same issue with `data` being undefined until any data is fetched and cached.

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const pokemonApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "pokemonApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/"
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPokemonByName: builder.query({
      query: () => "/pokemon",
      transformResponse: (response) => response.results
    })
  })
});

export const { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } = pokemonApi;
export default pokemonApi;
```

```
function PokemonCard() {
  const {
    data,
    error,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    isSuccess
  } = useGetPokemonByNameQuery();

  return (
    <ul>
      {isLoading && "...Loading..."}
      {isError && error.message}
      {isSuccess &&
        data.map((pokemon) => <li key={pokemon.name}>{pokemon.name}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

### Demo

[image: Edit pokemon-api-with-rdx-query-and-react-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined]

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) the main problem is, that its not show all pokemos with the weight, height, sprites and the base_experience. If I want to show in Browser, i get the error message :/

Comment: @Omer You may need to call a different API endpoint if you want different data then. The one you are using returns exactly what I shared above, each result array element is an object with `name` and `url` property.

Comment: @Omer Based on what I understand of the [API documentation](https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#resource-listspagination-section) it doesn't look like you get the specific data until querying for specific ids or names. You may need to make multiple requests to gather all the data you need for rendering. Does this make sense?

Comment: I've managed to achieve what you've done in your Codesandbox. However, I'm struggling to display additional data underneath the Pokémon, such as height, weight, and images of the Pokémon. I just can't seem to get it to work :( Do I need to add more endpoints for this to be displayed? Could you maybe show me that again in your Codesandbox?

Comment: I wanted to display this additional information for all the Pokémon in the browser, not just for one:

return (
    <ul>
      {isLoading && "...Loading..."}
      {isError && error.message}
      {isSuccess &&
        data.map((pokemon) => (
          <li key={pokemon.name}>
            <b> {pokemon.name}</b>
            <p>base_experience: </p>
            <p>height:</p>
            <p>weight:</p>
            <p>sprites/img</p>
          </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

Comment: @Omer You'll need to take the response you get from `"/pokemon"` and make a `"/pokemon/:name"` request for each element of the results array. If you need help with this other question/issue regarding composing the requests to get all the data you need then please create a new SO post specific to it. Has your question/post here regarding the error reading properties of an undefined reference been sufficiently addressed/resolved?

Answer (score -1):

Try calling your api using react query to fetch data from api then convert your data to json object as follows:

```
const {data, isLoading,error} = useQuery('data',async() => {
const response = await fetch('api url')
return response.json()
});
return (
 <>
  <ul>
    {isLoading && '...Loading...'}
    {isError && error.message}
    {data.map((pokemon) => (
    <li key={pokemon.id}>{pokemon.name}</li>
  ))}
  </ul>
 </>
);
```

Comment: its not working :(

Comment: [`fetchBaseQuery`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery) is a light wrapper around `fetch` that does a bit of the lifting for you, it handles [unpacking JSON responses by default](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#parsing-a-response) so you don't have to.